# Install PHP Calendar Extention

Tags: php

How do I install/enable php calendar in the server ?

I came upto https://www.php.net/manual/en/calendar.installation.php , but could not move more that that.

What is the full command, and do I have to download anything ? Do I need to move to any directory ? Do I need to do anything more ?

I wanted to run cal_days_in_month (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php) in the server, plus number of other functions that appear in the extention.

Comment: What platform does the server run? The documentation clearly states that the Windows version of PHP has this built in. On Linux, you either have to **recompile** PHP with the given flag (--enable-calendar) or install an apropriate module (or ask your server admin to do it for you)

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu or Debian, the "php-calendar" package can be used to enable it.